# How can I update mongoose subdocuments via form post request

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a Schema system with nested schemas to create a one to many relationship.

**User Schema**

```js
const expenseSchema = new Schema({
  expense: String,
  value: Number
});

const budgetSchema = new Schema({
  earnings: Number,
  expenses: [expenseSchema]
});

const userSchema = new Schema({
  username: String,
  name: String,
  googleId: String,
  budget: [budgetSchema]
});
```

I am trying to push a value to these nested schemas but been having some trouble. **Note** The req.user value is of authenticated users through Passport authentication

**This is my attempt to add data into the budget schema's earning property**. The weird thing is that when I log the user after the post request it shows undefined.

```js
router.post("/", (req, res) => {
  User.findOneAndUpdate(req.user, {
    $push: {
      budget: {
        earnings: req.body.earning
      }
    }
  });
  console.log(req.user);
});
```

Vue form

```js
submitBudget() {
  const expenses = this.mergeKeyAndValue();

  axios
    .post("http://localhost:3000/budget", {
      earning: this.earnings,
      expenses
    })
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response.data);
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.error(e);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
router.post("/", (req, res) => {
 User.findOneAndUpdate(req.user,
 {$push:{
   budget: {
     earnings: req.body.earning
   }
 }

 }
 )
  console.log(req.user);
})
```

In here, you are not providing a callback function to User.findOneAndUpdate() and without such function, all you're doing is querying the database without saving anything.

Taken from Mongoose docs about [Model.findOneAndUpdate()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate)

```
A.findOneAndUpdate(conditions, update, options, callback) // executes
A.findOneAndUpdate(conditions, update, options)  // returns Query
A.findOneAndUpdate(conditions, update, callback) // executes
A.findOneAndUpdate(conditions, update)           // returns Query -> This is what you are doing right now.
A.findOneAndUpdate()                             // returns Query
```

Additionally, your syntax is incorrect that's probably why you're getting undefined. It should be `Users.findOneAndUpdate({ username: req.user },.....` or wherever your `req.user` username key the request object holds is stored.

You can rewrite the whole function using async/await in the following way:

```
router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
    const update = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
        { username: req.user.username },
        {
            $push: {
                budget: {
                    earnings: req.body.earning
                }
            }
        }
    )
    console.log(update);
});
```

I don't have an easy way to test the `$push` update so I'm going to assume you know what you are doing but the rest should be as described.